# What happens to async awaitable code in C# if the associated UI is disposed

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

Say I have a WPF dialog in which I have async event handlers that await some call that takes a long time. Then the user closes the dialog (and the code disposes it) before that await has returned.  I would imagine that would cause a crash. Is there a prescribed way to handle this scenario using the new async/await keywords in C# 5 with the new TaskAsync methods in .NET 4.5?

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but have you considered preventing the user from closing the dialog box until the operation completes? I don't know how well this fits in with the user experience of your application, it's just a direction to consider.

Comment: Perhaps it is just the toy demos I've seen, but none seem to take this scenario into consideration. I'll look into cancellation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`async`/`await` should work fine.

[Each WPF window does create its own `SynchronizationContext`](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2009/09/another-synchronizationcontext-gotcha.html) - at least right now (this is an implementation detail). But these are just simple wrappers around the common `Dispatcher`.

So, `TaskAwaiter` will end up capturing a `SynchronizationContext` for a window that gets destroyed, but it doesn't really matter because the `Dispatcher` is still there.

Now, what your code does is another story. e.g., if you have an `async` event handler in this situation, it has to be able to handle resuming on a disposed instance.

Both Adam and leppie have good comments: either prevent the user from closing the dialog, or cancel the task (and ensure it is cancelled before actually closing the dialog). Another good option - if your idea is to start an operation that *should* outlast the dialog - is to start the `Task` and then add it to a shared collection of in-progress operations. All of these options prevent the undesirable situation of an `async` event handler running on a disposed instance.

Answer (score 1):

I think this depends on the exact situation. If you have code in an `async` method on a `Dispose()`d object, it can continue just fine, because `Dispose()` doesn't mean anything to the framework. Of course, if the method calls some method that will throw `ObjectDisposedException` (or some other exception), that will stop the async operation (unless you catch the exception). But it doesn't happen automatically.